# Workplace viewport scripting

Tags: automation, casc

Working with DevOps toolchains requires switching contexts between code, dashboards and command line terminals (local and remote). That is just for one project - and many of us work in more than one.

To reduce switching and navigating, folks and me too use more and more monitors - 4K (UHD) is a welcomed technology.

Say altogether, a set of windows and terminals for a context is a DevOps viewport (or maybe there is a better word).

Now, what are - if any - convenient means to "script" windows/terminals configurations as a CasC (Configuration as Code) artefact so you could easily load and switch your CI/CD environment viewports?

- Windows 10 environment?
- Ubuntu Linux environent?

Comment: Care to elaborate on what you mean by a CaSC like artifact? I have never heard the term before.

Comment: @PrestonM **C**onfiguration as **C**ode

Answer (score 1):

There are tools around the web for saving desktops. Still best solution I found out to be running a set of virtual machines on your computer, having one setup in one vm.

That takes some space, but you can save the state of vm upon vm shut down and come back to exactly same state when you come back. Maybe sessions have died but the windows certainly are as you left them.

Solution is stated on http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/save-restore-windows-session/ and it is for windows but I suppose the same will apply for Linux vm too.